# R not finishing looping through dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

This function I wrote to loop through a Sas.7bdat dataset is getting stuck at the 62 column. When I defined the output dataframe outside the function definition it was getting stuck at the 8,000 column. all im trying to do is replace every value greater than 0 with a 1, and anything less than or equal to 0 with a 0.

```
# data
fecal_lcms <- haven::read_sas(path)

# function definition
main1 <- function(input){
  
  output <- matrix(nrow = nrow(input), ncol = ncol(input))

  for( i in 15:ncol(input) ){

    for( j in 1:nrow(input[i]) ){

      if( input[j,i] > 0 ) { output[j,i] <- 1 }
      if( input[j,i] <= 0 | is.na(input[j,i]) == TRUE ) { output[j,i] <- 0}
      else{ next }
    }
  }
  output <<- output
}

# Call the function
main1(fecal_lcms)
```

```
dput(fecal_lcms[1:10, 61:63])
```

```
structure(list(p_47 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
183.512572776756), format.sas = "BEST"), p_48 = structure(c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1739.26624992498), format.sas = "BEST"), 
    p_49 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 377.112281000271
    ), format.sas = "BEST")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What do you mean "getting stuck" - is there an error? A warning? If so, what does it say? Can you share a little bit of reproducible sample data? Since the trouble happens at column 62, maybe you could share 5 or 10 rows for columns 61-63? `dput(fecal_lcms[1:10, 61:63])` will make a copy/pasteable version of that subset of data including all class and structure info.

Comment: Speaking of class and structure info, have you looked at column 62 to see if it seems different from the other columns?

Comment: Also, I'd strongly advise against using global assignment with `<<-`. Have your function `return(output)` and then assign the result when you call the function, `output <- main1(fecal_lcms)`. That's the standard R way to do things, and lets you be flexible with the name of the result.

Comment: no errors, it just runs until i press the 'stop' icon above the console (im using rstudio). I checked the class of the column, its the same as all the others (numeric)

Comment: If you press "stop" during the for loop, then the `output <<- output` never ran and nothing should have changed in the global environment. And I'm then confused why you think column 62 is an issue.

Comment: all the columns preceding 62 are 1's and zeros, everything after is not. and its the same wether i let it run for 1 sec, 10 mins, or half and hour

Comment: That means that you have an object called `output` that looks like that in your environment from an early run that completed. When you stop your code before it completes, it has no lasting effect. If you `rm(output)` to remove what you're starting with, you'll see that you have no `output` at all when you stop the code early. That said, use the method in Carl's answer. This should take milliseconds.

Comment: If the `for` loop wasn't inside a function, the changes would be made to the object iteratively--this is probably what happened: In your debugging you ran the for loop directly, but stopped it when it got to column 62. R's scoping rules keep what happens inside the function from effecting things outside of the function except when you use global assignment like `<<-`. You are stopping the function before it gets to `<<-`, so all internal results are gone. Anytime you've called the function and then clicked the Stop button, there has been no saved change.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to replace the numbers, why don't you use the following approach with lapply? Since you have not provided any data, I have created a simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,-2,3,4,-5), b = c(2,NA,4,-7,-8))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x <= 0 | is.na(x), 0, 1))
```

EDIT: As mentioned by Gregor Thomas in the comments, it is not even necessary to use lapply:

```
df[] <- ifelse(df <= 0 | is.na(df), 0, 1)
```

Comment: Use `df[] <-`, we don't even need `lapply`: `df[] <- ifelse(df <= 0 | is.na(df), 0, 1)` works fine.

Comment: (And skipping the `lapply` it will work nicely on a matrix or a data frame--which I mention since OP was using a `matrix`.)